# Average two values in consecutive observations in SAS - account for extra hour in fall time change

Tags: sas, average, dst

I have data like the following for dates over several years:

```
Date           HE       Value
04NOV2007       1       981.00
04NOV2007       2       925.00
04NOV2007       3       900.00
04NOV2007       4       875.00
04NOV2007       5       880.00
04NOV2007       6       894.00
04NOV2007       7       946.00
04NOV2007       8       982.00
04NOV2007       9      1051.00 
04NOV2007      10      1122.00
04NOV2007      11      1167.00
04NOV2007      12      1194.00
04NOV2007      13      1203.00
04NOV2007      14      1199.00
04NOV2007      15      1200.00
04NOV2007      16      1194.00
04NOV2007      17      1203.00
04NOV2007      18      1238.00
04NOV2007      19      1379.00
04NOV2007      20      1402.00
04NOV2007      21      1357.00
04NOV2007      22      1300.00
04NOV2007      23      1205.00
04NOV2007      24      1093.00
04NOV2007      24       994.00
```

In order to eliminate an extra observation created on the date of the fall time change, I need to average the values from HE2 and HE3, replace the value of HE2 with the new value and then delete the HE3 observation before shifting the other hours. Shifting the HE values to increment by one is no problem, but I am not sure of the most efficient way to complete the task of averaging HE2 and HE3. In my full dataset, I have 24 hours for each date (not shown for brevity's sake). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you always trying to do this on HE2 and HE3? Would it be a problem to average the HE24 observations?

Comment: I was directed to average HE2 and HE3 since that is when the time change happens. This is specific electricity load data that will be used in forecasting so getting as close to the actual value for the hour is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume there's some sort of indicator for when the time change happens. Since we know it's at HE2 and HE3, we'll use the values of 2 and 3 directly for this example. Averaging two values is simply summing them and dividing by two.

We'll store the value of `HE` in the variable `sum_values`. Next, we'll check which `HE` we're in. If we're in 2, let's delete the row and do nothing further. If we're in 3, let's replace the value with the total values we've summed up and divide it by the number of values we're averaging (in this case, two). We'll then set its value of HE to 2.

```
data want;
    set have;
    by date he;

    if(HE IN(2,3) ) then do;
        sum_values+value;
        n_values+1;

        if(HE = 2) then delete;
            else if(HE = 3) then do;
                value = sum_values/n_values;
                HE    = 2;
           end;
    end;
run;
```

This works if your data looks like the above, but if you have other relevant variables that are dependent on `HE2` and need to replace `HE3` then you'd need to carry those variables forward in temporary retained variables.